# pronounceability algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, function

I am struggling to find/create an algorithm that can determine the pronounceability of random 5 letter combinations.

The closest thing I've found so far is from this 3 year old StackOverflow thread:

[Measure the pronounceability of a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186213/measure-the-pronounceability-of-a-word)

```
<?php
// Score: 1
echo pronounceability('namelet') . "\n";

// Score: 0.71428571428571
echo pronounceability('nameoic') . "\n";

function pronounceability($word) {
    static $vowels = array
        (
        'a',
        'e',
        'i',
        'o',
        'u',
        'y'
        );

    static $composites = array
        (
        'mm',
        'll',
        'th',
        'ing'
        );

    if (!is_string($word)) return false;

    // Remove non letters and put in lowercase
    $word = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $word);
    $word = strtolower($word);

    // Special case
    if ($word == 'a') return 1;

    $len = strlen($word);

    // Let's not parse an empty string
    if ($len == 0) return 0;

    $score = 0;
    $pos = 0;

    while ($pos < $len) {
        // Check if is allowed composites
        foreach ($composites as $comp) {
                $complen = strlen($comp);

                if (($pos + $complen) < $len) {
                        $check = substr($word, $pos, $complen);

                        if ($check == $comp) {
                                $score += $complen;
                                $pos += $complen;
                                continue 2;
                        }
                }
        }

        // Is it a vowel? If so, check if previous wasn't a vowel too.
        if (in_array($word[$pos], $vowels)) {
                if (($pos - 1) >= 0 && !in_array($word[$pos - 1], $vowels)) {
                        $score += 1;
                        $pos += 1;
                        continue;
                }
        } else { // Not a vowel, check if next one is, or if is end of word
                if (($pos + 1) < $len && in_array($word[$pos + 1], $vowels)) {
                        $score += 2;
                        $pos += 2;
                        continue;
                } elseif (($pos + 1) == $len) {
                        $score += 1;
                        break;
                }
        }

        $pos += 1;
    }

    return $score / $len;
}
?>
```

... but it is far from perfect, giving some rather strange false positives:

Using this function, all of the following rate as pronounceable, (above 7/10)

- ZTEDA
- LLFDA
- MMGDA
- THHDA
- RTHDA
- XYHDA
- VQIDA

Can someone smarter than me tweek this algorithm perhaps so that:

- 'MM', 'LL', and 'TH' are only valid when followed or preceeded by a
  vowel?
- 3 or more consonants in a row is a no-no, (except when the first or
  last is an 'R' or 'L')
- any other refinements you can think of...

*(I have done a fair amount of research/googling, and this seems to be the main pronounceability function that everyone has been referencing/using for the last 3 years, so I'm sure an updated, more refined version would be appreciated by the wider community, not just me!).*

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [`metaphone`](http://php.net/metaphone) key of the word and see how "pronouncable" it is?

Comment: If you are testing pronounceability of words, why not test it against actual words?  Giving garbled text is bound to give weird results... Are you expecting that type of input?  Finally, what about "raising the bar"? Push the threshold of pronounceable up to 8/10?

Comment: Your suggested rule 1 would outlaw words like "Phenolphthalein" - not easy to pronounce, but a perfectly valid word. Your suggested rule 2 would outlaw words like 'fully'.

Comment: rule 2 also prohibits 'strengths' and 'strength', although I admit, they are longer than 5 characters.

Comment: In reference to some of the comments above: **Kolink** - I like the idea of using a [metaphone](http://php.net/metaphone) key, but I still need to calculate how pronouncable the key is, which is the hard part. Perhaps as there is a limited number of 5 character metaphone keys, it would be possible to generate a 'white list'?
**Lix** - the objective is to find new pronouncable 5 letter combinations, so using actual words is a no-no. In fact I want to ignore "real" words.

Comment: **Penguino** and **Xantix** - I am trying to generate new brandable 5 letter company names, like Yahoo, Cisco, Skype, Xerox, Kodak, Pepsi... Words like "Phenolphthalein", whilst still valid words, would fall into my "not very pronouncable" category. I am only interested in 5 letter combinations with "good pronouncablity", not valid words.

Comment: @NeilHillman how did you get on mate? its been 1 year and 4 months. Haven't heard from you in relation to this post

Comment: I gave up on it actually - I would still be interested in this as a project, but I decided it was slightly beyond my skill level as a programmer, so I moved on to more achievable goals.

Comment: Define pronounceable. To me, the word 2, 3, 5 and 6 are pronounceable. I even include rthda as a word that is very easy to pronounce. Also, some vowelless words are pronounceable like fscks.

Answer (score 9):

Based on a suggestion on the linked question to "Use a Markov model on letters"

> Use a Markov model (on letters, not words, of course). The probability of a word is a pretty good proxy for ease of pronunciation.

I thought I would try it out and had some success.

## My Methodology

I copied a list of real 5-letter words into a file to serve as my dataset ([here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/adam.bozon/Scrabble5.htm)...um, actually [here](http://www.becomeawordgameexpert.com/wordlists5.htm)).

Then I use a Hidden Markov model (based on One-grams, Bi-grams, and Tri-grams) to predict how likely a target word would appear in that dataset.

(Better results could be achieved with some sort of phonetic transcription as one of the steps.)

First, I calculate the probabilities of character sequences in the dataset.

For example, if 'A' occurs 50 times, and there is only 250 characters in the dataset, then 'A' has a 50/250 or .2 probability.

Do the same for the bigrams 'AB', 'AC', ...

Do the same for the trigrams 'ABC', 'ABD', ...

Basically, my score for the word "ABCDE" is composed of:

- prob( 'A' )
- prob( 'B' )
- prob( 'C' )
- prob( 'D' )
- prob( 'E' )
- prob( 'AB' )
- prob( 'BC' )
- prob( 'CD' )
- prob( 'DE' )
- prob( 'ABC' )
- prob( 'BCD' )
- prob( 'CDE' )

You could multiply all of these together to get the estimated probability of the target word appearing in the dataset, (but that is very small).

So instead, we take the logs of each and add them together.

Now we have a score which estimates how likely our target word would appear in the dataset.

## My code

I have coded this is C#, and find that a score greater than negative 160 is pretty good.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Pronouncability
{

class Program
{
    public static char[] alphabet = new char[]{ 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' };

    public static List<string> wordList = loadWordList(); //Dataset of 5-letter words

    public static Random rand = new Random();

    public const double SCORE_LIMIT = -160.00;

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates random words, until 100 of them are better than
    /// the SCORE_LIMIT based on a statistical score. 
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<Tuple<char, char, char>, int> trigramCounts = new Dictionary<Tuple<char, char, char>, int>();

        Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int> bigramCounts = new Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int>();

        Dictionary<char, int> onegramCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        calculateProbabilities(onegramCounts, bigramCounts, trigramCounts);

        double totalTrigrams = (double)trigramCounts.Values.Sum();
        double totalBigrams = (double)bigramCounts.Values.Sum();
        double totalOnegrams = (double)onegramCounts.Values.Sum();

        SortedList<double, string> randomWordsScores = new SortedList<double, string>();

        while( randomWordsScores.Count < 100 )
        {
            string randStr = getRandomWord();

            if (!randomWordsScores.ContainsValue(randStr))
            {
                double score = getLikelyhood(randStr,trigramCounts, bigramCounts, onegramCounts, totalTrigrams, totalBigrams, totalOnegrams);

                if (score > SCORE_LIMIT)
                {
                    randomWordsScores.Add(score, randStr);
                }
            }
        }


        //Right now randomWordsScores contains 100 random words which have 
        //a better score than the SCORE_LIMIT, sorted from worst to best.
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a random 5-letter word
    /// </summary>
    public static string getRandomWord()
    {
        char c0 = (char)rand.Next(65, 90);
        char c1 = (char)rand.Next(65, 90);
        char c2 = (char)rand.Next(65, 90);
        char c3 = (char)rand.Next(65, 90);
        char c4 = (char)rand.Next(65, 90);

        return "" + c0 + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a score for how likely a given word is, based on given trigrams, bigrams, and one-grams
    /// </summary>
    public static double getLikelyhood(string wordToScore, Dictionary<Tuple<char, char,char>, int> trigramCounts, Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int> bigramCounts, Dictionary<char, int> onegramCounts, double totalTrigrams, double totalBigrams, double totalOnegrams)
    {
        wordToScore = wordToScore.ToUpper();

        char[] letters = wordToScore.ToCharArray();

        Tuple<char, char>[] bigrams = new Tuple<char, char>[]{ 

            new Tuple<char,char>( wordToScore[0], wordToScore[1] ),
            new Tuple<char,char>( wordToScore[1], wordToScore[2] ),
            new Tuple<char,char>( wordToScore[2], wordToScore[3] ),
            new Tuple<char,char>( wordToScore[3], wordToScore[4] )

        };

        Tuple<char, char, char>[] trigrams = new Tuple<char, char, char>[]{ 

            new Tuple<char,char,char>( wordToScore[0], wordToScore[1], wordToScore[2] ),
            new Tuple<char,char,char>( wordToScore[1], wordToScore[2], wordToScore[3] ),
            new Tuple<char,char,char>( wordToScore[2], wordToScore[3], wordToScore[4] ),


        };

        double score = 0;

        foreach (char c in letters)
        {
            score += Math.Log((((double)onegramCounts[c]) / totalOnegrams));
        }

        foreach (Tuple<char, char> pair in bigrams)
        {
            score += Math.Log((((double)bigramCounts[pair]) / totalBigrams));
        }

        foreach (Tuple<char, char, char> trio in trigrams)
        {
            score += 5.0*Math.Log((((double)trigramCounts[trio]) / totalTrigrams));
        }


        return score;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build the probability tables based on the dataset (WordList)
    /// </summary>
    public static void calculateProbabilities(Dictionary<char, int> onegramCounts, Dictionary<Tuple<char, char>, int> bigramCounts, Dictionary<Tuple<char, char, char>, int> trigramCounts)
    {
        foreach (char c1 in alphabet)
        {
            foreach (char c2 in alphabet)
            {
                foreach( char c3 in alphabet)
                {
                    trigramCounts[new Tuple<char, char, char>(c1, c2, c3)] = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach( char c1 in alphabet)
        {
            foreach( char c2 in alphabet)
            {
                bigramCounts[ new Tuple<char,char>(c1,c2) ] = 1;
            }
        }

        foreach (char c1 in alphabet)
        {
            onegramCounts[c1] = 1;
        }


        foreach (string word in wordList)
        {
            for (int pos = 0; pos < 3; pos++)
            {
                trigramCounts[new Tuple<char, char, char>(word[pos], word[pos + 1], word[pos + 2])]++;
            }

            for (int pos = 0; pos < 4; pos++)
            {
                bigramCounts[new Tuple<char, char>(word[pos], word[pos + 1])]++;
            }

            for (int pos = 0; pos < 5; pos++)
            {
                onegramCounts[word[pos]]++;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the dataset (WordList) from file.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<string> loadWordList()
    {
        string filePath = "WordList.txt";

        string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        List<string> result = text.Split(' ').ToList();

        return result;
    }
}

}
```

In my example, I scale the trigram probabilities by 5.

I also add one to all of the counts, so we don't multiply by zero.

## Final notes

I'm not a php programmer, but the technique is pretty easy to implement.

Play around with some scaling factors, try different datasets, or add in some other checks like what you suggested above.

Comment: **Xantix** - this looks really interesting, but unfortunately I don't know C#. I will have a go to see if I can follow it enough to write an equivalent function in PHP, and test it out...  _if anyone more familar with C# wants to try to port this to PHP, I would be very grateful..._ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

How about generating a reasonably pronounceable combination from the start?  I have done something where I generate a random [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) code, and work back from that to a (usually) pronounceable original.

Comment: This sounds similar to **Kolink**'s [Metaphone](http://php.net/metaphone) key suggestion. I wondered if, as there would only be a limited number of Soundex / Metaphone keys, it would be possible to generate a "white list" of pronounceable key combinations, and match all new combinations against this list?

Comment: There are slightly less that 26,000 Soundex codes.  Each code can lead to a lot of words.  In my experience most of them are either pronounceable, or close to it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's looking for a way to do this with Node.js, I found a module called [pronouncable](https://github.com/lukem512/pronounceable) that seems to implement what Xantix's answer describes.

```
npm i pronounceable
```

You can [test in without installing anything on RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/pronounceable).